# Product of Lindelöf metric space is Lindelöf

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If I have a metric space $(X,d)$ that is Lindelöf? Will the product of $X$ and itself $X \times X$ be Lindelöf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Hints:

1) $X \times X$ is still metrizable since $X$ is metrizable.

2) separable and Lindelöf are equivalent in the metrizable space, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122528/a-question-on-metrizable-space).

3) $X \times X$ is still separable since $X$ is separable.

Comment: Why is X metrizable?

Comment: since you have a metric space $(X,d)$, $X$ is metrizable.

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: One of the first things that you prove in studying metric spaces is that the product of two (and hence of finitely many) metric spaces is metric. You may even have proved that the product of countably infinitely many metric spaces is metric.